# get process ids for multiple processes returns the same process id in bash

Tags: bash

I'm using trying to get the process ids for several bash processes:

```
./test_run.sh hello
echo $$
./test_run.sh hellos
echo $$
./test_run.sh hello22
echo $$
```

definition of test_run.sh

```
echo "run $1"
```

but they all return the same process ids, why?

Answer (score 2):

`$$` returns the PID of the current shell process. To get the PID of the background process you just started, use `$!`.

```
./test_run.sh hello &
echo $!
./test_run.sh hello &
echo $!
```

Comment: All you did was change the arguments to `test_run.sh`. What difference does that make to the question?

Comment: $$ returns the same pid and $! returns "" in the updated question.  I expect $$ to return different pids

Comment: Oh, I see you're not putting them in the background any more `$!` is only for background processes. Why do you expect `$$` to return different PIDs? The PID of the original shell doesn't change when you run a command. The command run in a child process, but the original shell process stays the same.